# SmartTabLayout : Como usar ícones nas abas ao invés de texto?

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, eu estou utilizando abas no meu app de aprendizado com a biblioteca SmartTabLayout, vou deixar abaixo uma imagem de como elas estão (a imagem é da internet, mas serve apenas para mostrar o mesmo modelo que eu fiz aqui), e eu gostaria de fazer apenas uma mudança nessas abas, ao invés de aparecer esses textos nas abas, aparecer um ícone em cada aba, apenas isso. Não consigo achar nada sobre isso na documentação da biblioteca e nem em nenhum lugar na internet que seja este mesmo modelo só que com ícones. De acordo com a imagem abaixo, é como se fosse apenas tirar o texto HOME e colocar um ícone no lugar dele.

Vou deixar o código xml e da activity que eu usei para a construção das abas. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito :P

[image: Esse é o modelo que tenho agora]

```
Código XML:
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewPagerTab" />
```

Código da classe:

```
FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager() ,
                FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                        .add("Salas Oficiais" , SalasOficiaisFragment.class)
                        .add("Salas Criadas" , SalasCriadasFragment.class)
                        .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerTab);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Está biblioteca que está usando  https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout?
Se for, tente seguir o método descrito pelo autor da biblioteca https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout/issues/34

Comment: Sim, estou usando essa biblioteca, eu tentei fazer igual desse que vc mandou mas não deu certo, nem consegui fazer direito pois lá no xml da resposta tem um TextView e eu não sei o que é ele e onde colocar, pois aqui no meu nos códigos da biblioteca não tem um textView assim, tem apenas esses códigos que mandei acima no xml e esses na classe e só com isso já aparece as abas, só que queria que aparecesse apenas um ícone em cada aba, ao invés de uma string. Na linha: .add("Conversas" , SalasCriadasFragment.class), esse primeiro parametro só aceita String, aí que tá.. gostaria q fosse um ícone

Comment: Fiz aqui e funcionou, testa essa minha resposta e me avisa em caso de dúvida. Abraço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta da seguinte maneira:

**Crie uma classe com nome de `TintableImageView` e deixe assim:**

```
public class TintableImageView extends ImageView {

  private ColorStateList tint;

  public TintableImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs, R.styleable.TintableImageView, defStyle, 0);
    tint = a.getColorStateList(
        R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint);
    a.recycle();
  }

  @Override
  protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (tint != null && tint.isStateful()) {
      updateTintColor();
    }
  }

  public void setColorFilter(ColorStateList tint) {
    this.tint = tint;
    super.setColorFilter(tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0));
  }

  private void updateTintColor() {
    int color = tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
    setColorFilter(color);
  }

}
```

**em res/values crie um xml com nome de `attrs` e acrescente:**

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="TintableImageView">
    <attr name="tint" format="reference|color"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**em res/layout crie um xml com nome de `custom_tab_icon` e coloque:**

```
<!-- Em yourPackge acrescente o pacote da sua aplicação-->
<yourPackage.TintableImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:tint="@drawable/custom_color_icon"
    />
```

**em res/drawable crie o seguinte xml com nome de `custom_color_icon`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#73D3C7" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="#FF63727B" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Nele você define as cores dos icones.

**No xml em que está o seu ViewPager, acima do ViewPager acrescente:**

```
<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
    app:stl_dividerColor="#00000000"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#33FFFFFF"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="500dp"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="linear"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="36dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth= "36dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="true"
    app:stl_underlineColor="#00000000"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp"/>
```

**E por fim na sua Activity onde está o ViewPager deixa da seguinte maneira:**

```
 FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                .add("Salas Oficiais" , SalasOficiaisFragment.class)
                .add("Salas Criadas" , SalasCriadasFragment.class)
                .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final Resources res = getResources();

        viewPagerTab.setCustomTabView(new SmartTabLayout.TabProvider() {
            @Override
            public View createTabView(ViewGroup container, int position, PagerAdapter adapter) {

                ImageView icon = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_icon, container,
                        false);
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.seuVector_24dp, null));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.seuVector2_24dp, null));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid position: " + position);
                }

                return icon;
            }
        });

        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Não esqueça de criar os icones que irá utilizar em Vetor.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora a responder, eu tinha deixado de tentar fazer isso por um tempo, mas irei ver aqui se consigo com o seu código, agora que vi sua resposta, provavelmente com isso vai dar certo sim